# Show that the sequence $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}}$ is bounded if $\alpha>1, a_1\in(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequnce of positive numbers satisfying $$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha}},  \alpha>1, a_1\in (0,1),$$ prove that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

I tried this way:

$$ \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n+\frac{a_n^{\alpha}}{n^\alpha}}=\frac{n^{\alpha}}{a_n n^{\alpha}+a_n^{\alpha}}=\frac{1}{a_n}\left(1-\frac{a_n^{\alpha-1}}{n^{\alpha}+a_n^{\alpha-1}}\right)=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{a_n^{\alpha-2}}{n^\alpha+a_n^{\alpha-1}}$$

$$ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{a_k}\right)+\frac{1}{a_1}=
 -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k^{\alpha-2}}{k^{\alpha}+a_k^{\alpha-1}}+\frac{1}{a_1}$$

Then I want to prove that this formula is greater than a certain positive number, but failed. I am not sure whether the way is effective. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The technique should be the same.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ, in this case, this post is a duplicate and so we have to close it.

Comment: $$
\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{k+1}-a_k)\le \int_{x=1}^{x=n}\frac{a(x)^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha}}dx
$$